# How to backup my memory card without a PC?

Tags: memory-card, backup

I'm going to travel for a long time and won't have access to PC or internet.
I want to backup my photos from my memory card to my hard drive.
Is there any solution that copies photos directly from a memory card or from a card reader to a hard drive?

If not, is there any other way to backup a lot of photos, other than using lots of memory cards?

**Note**: By PC I mean also any other computers or net books. I'm looking for something small that you can carry in your backpack.

Comment: One approach might be [What devices transfer photos from one flash media to another?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9170/what-devices-transfer-photos-from-one-flash-media-to-another)