# How to backup my flash card without computer

Tags: backup, compactflash

I travel a lot, mainly in Asia, and take a lot of photos in each of my trips.

Can you recommend me a device to backup my photos from my flash card to another external drive without using a computer?

Cloud storage is not working for me, because the places I visit are often without internet and mobile coverage.

Comment: Here are some of the devices that does what you want http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Stand-Alone-Data-Storage/ci/3369/N/4000227848

Comment: I think this is answered quite well here https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9170/what-devices-transfer-photos-from-one-flash-media-to-another