# Portable Storage Device while traveling

Tags: travel, portable, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I backup my RAW photos while travelling without Internet access?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-can-i-backup-my-raw-photos-while-travelling-without-internet-access)

I need storage device which is able to read CF cards and make a backup of my photos while traveling. I do not want to carry laptop (it's bulky) and tablet (too little storage) but looking into some other solutions.

So far I found:

- Epson PXXXX - price is blocker for me
- Jobo Giga Vu - same as above
- Nexto DI - bit better, but still a lot
- Hyperdrive Colorspace UDMA - this looks the best for price/options
- Wolwerine PicPac - cheap, bad opinions
- DigitalFoci PhotoSafe - same as above
- Ex-Pro® Picture 2 Drive - didn't find much about it

So ladys & gents what do you use?