# Feature differences of Photobackup devices

Tags: travel, backup, storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I backup my RAW photos while travelling without Internet access?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-can-i-backup-my-raw-photos-while-travelling-without-internet-access)

**Disclaimer:** long question.

While this covers the grounds of [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-can-i-backup-my-raw-photos-while-travelling-without-internet-access) I would like updated awnsers, since some of the devices listed there are not available any longer. FUrthermore I would like to get some more information on the devices themselve and the experience you made with them.

### The basic situation:

- need to backup pictures on the go *without* a laptop/netbook/smartphone
- would like the solution to be powergrid independent (**battery powerable**)
- have a lumix g camera and shoot raw => picturereviewing only valuable if **rw2** format capable
- would like to have some visual confirmation of backup/copying success, since I might reuse my memory cards for further shooting (=> backup becomes only copy)
- need SDHC card slot
- weight is an issue
- looked for usb bridges/usb on the go devices but they seem to have stopped those back in 2010.

For some of the devices I consider I did not find the manufacturers site, so I have only lacking amazon product descriptions. I would like to have the links to the datasheets/usermanual were I could not find them, know if the device supports rw2 (maybe list other raw formats for owners of different cameras?), supports creation of subfolders (not that important), and upsides/downsides.

---

### The devices [1]

**Nexto ND2730** [manufacturer: Nexto](http://www.nextodi.com), [datasheet](http://www.nextodi.com/product/en_nd2730.html)

- Raw formats: rw2, cr2, nef, arw
- Card formats: sdhc, sd, sdxc, cf
- Transfer/Charge: ??
- HDD: Choose yourself
- Filemanagement: ???
- weight 130g + hdd
- price: 215€ + hdd

**VOSONIC VP8870** [manufacturer: Istego??], [datasheeet??]

- Raw formats: nef and ???
- Card formats: sdhc and ???
- Transfer/Charge: 40GB
- HDD: 160 -1000GB, here 500GB version
- Filemanagement: move/copy/folder
- weight: 327g
- price: 415€

*DOWNSIDE*:As of writing this I can't reach the manufacturers page (a [Docma article](http://www.docma.info/docma-archiv/archiv/vosonic-bildspeicher.html) suggests that the manufacturer is called istego, and google suggests they are out of buisness, can anyone confirm this?)

**HyperDrive COLORSPACE UDMA2** [manufacturer: hyperdrive](http://www.amazon.de/HyperDrive-Colorspace-UDMA-160GB/dp/B003X3VCYO), [datasheeet??]

- Raw formats: ???
- Card formats: sdhc, sd, cf, sdxc, mmc
- Transfer/Charge: 250GB
- HDD: 160 -1000GB
- Filemanagement: move/copy/folder
- weight: ???
- price: 267€ + hdd

*UPSIDE*: Mediaplayer included

**PiCPacII** [manufacturer: Wolverine](http://secure.mm5server.com/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=WD&Category_Code=FlashPac), [datasheeet??]

- Raw formats: none
- Card formats: sdhc, sd,, micro sd, cf, sdxc, mmc
- Transfer/Charge: ???
- HDD: 160 -500GB, here 500Gb
- Filemanagement: none
- weight: 220g
- price:  $189.99 (presumably plus tax and customs)

*DOWNSIDE*: No picture/folderpreview only a message telling you the copy is done, heared about bad reviews.

---

**Questions:**

1. Do you own such a device and can you recommend it or not?
2. Do you know more about the features of such a device (Can you create folders,does it support rw2/Link to a datasheet)?

[1] datasheet or manufacturer page with detailed information, prices are for germany (geizhals.de) and might be outdated, all information without waranty