# Help with storage space

Tags: canon, raw, storage

Hi everyone I wonder if you could help me?
I am going on a trip where I will be out in the field for about a week and although I have a lot of CF cards for my Canon 7D its quite expensive to buy card after card. Can you get battery operated portable Hard Drives with a CF reader built into that you can copy RAW files onto? If so what do people recommend?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Approximately how many photos are we talking about here?

Comment: Umm maybe about 500 to 3700

Comment: I think the answers will depend a lot on whether it's 500 or 3700. 500 7D RAW files is about 16 Gb, at which point you don't even need to worry about multiple CF cards. 3700 may start being a different problem, although you may want to be worrying more about what your backup strategy is rather than how to store them all once.

Comment: Thanks Philip for your answers. I am kinda wondering about back up as well. I guess if I copy them onto some kind of battery operated portable hard drive that would be a good idea but I don't know if that is possible or if it is possible what kind to buy. I am going to be out for a week takeing photos of birds so I guess I would be taking 3000+

Comment: SE, in generally, doesn't do product recommendations and shopping questions tend to get closed down. You may want to remote the "what do people recommend" bit or edit it more to "what features should I look for..."

Comment: Also see: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-can-i-backup-my-raw-photos-while-travelling-without-internet-access

Comment: For specific products, you could try Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange. This question may be helpful: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7858/portable-hard-drive-with-sd-card-reader

Comment: How many versions of this same question do we need?

Comment: https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bbackup%5d%20travel

Comment: Decent 64 gb CF card are about $60 and you can put about 2500 images on it. Buying one more is probably cheaper than any other solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I backup my RAW photos while travelling without Internet access?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-can-i-backup-my-raw-photos-while-travelling-without-internet-access)

Answer (score 1):

*While the OTG method was already mention and sounds very attractive. I never managed to get it to work with any of the phone I tried. It just never mounted two storage devices at once.*

Back when my cameras were using Compact Flash cards, I had the perfect solution which will work for you. It is a portable DVD burner with built-in memory card readers for multiple formats. It can be both battery or A/C powered and the battery lasts for 10 burns in a single charge which gives you 47 GB of backups between recharges. This is ideal since DVDs are incredibly cheap and durable. They have no value to anyone else (so unlikely to be stolen) and you can get backups by duplicating each card into 2 disks. I used to do this, keep one copy with me and mail myself the other. Replication and distribution which is what you want for backups.

Saldy for me, they never updated it to support SDXC cards. So what is left is to backup to an external drive but those are costly. You must buy a $200-300 portable case with card reader, plus the storage inside it. One can use a standard HDD but that is very risky, so you must really go to SSDs which as you may know are costly.

The bottom line is that buying more CF cards will probably be the most cost-effective solution. CF cards are also incredibly sturdy and much less likely to fail than other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android phone or tablet with an SD card (say 128GB), then you can use a card reader and an OTG cable to backup up your cards to the phone or tablet.  This assumes that your device can act as a USB host. (I don't know if this is possible with an Apple device or not)

I have used this option myself for a trip to Cuba last year. The cost depends on what you already have on hand.

In my own case, I copied them to the tablet and to USB sticks (cheap) so I had 2 backups of everything.  I did an end of day backup from the card I used to the tablet.

If you don't have compatible devices already, then it might be cheaper to simply buy more cards, but the tablet is a nice solution that also allows you to view and/or edit if you want, as well as use for any other non photography related activities.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you seem to be asking for is one of the [Sanho HyperDrive ColorSpace UDMA 3 Wireless Storage Device](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1191264-REG/sanho_shdcsudma3000_casing_only_for_udma.html) models. Having never used them I can't exactly recommend them, but these check the "battery powered storage" and "CF compatible" boxes.

That said, I wouldn't buy one of these in order to be able to re-use CF cards in the field. I'd buy one to back up my CF cards during the trip, and buy more CF cards in order to shoot more. At $1/GB, cards are much cheaper than film ever was, and if you already own "a lot" of them you shouldn't need that many more to cover a week of shooting.