# What can I do when I suddenly cannot view older photos taken with my camera while on vacation?

Tags: canon, sdcard, sdhc, image-review

So I am currently on vacation and taking photos as usual and all of a sudden my camera is not showing my old photos (from the current trip) and when I try to scroll back it just gets stuck on busy. What went wrong? Are my photos lost? Should I take more or would this make things worse? 
My sd card is sandisk (I think class 10? It says 80mb/s)

Comment: Do you have a computer at hand? Saving (new) pictures to a potentially faulty card is a bad idea!

Comment: No, I am still on vacation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The card has probably developed an error. Flash cards (including SD cards) have a limited number of writes, and, while the expected number is large, sometimes failures happen early. Or it could simply be a manufacturing defect. In either of these cases, Sandisk — which has awesome long warranty periods ­— will probably replace the card, but that doesn't do any good for your older photos.

You should *definitely* stop using it now. Writing more data may make recovery harder, but, also, you may lose the whole card. If you don't have a backup one and care about photos you make take on the rest of vacation, it's worth paying tourist prices for a new SD card.

That said, the next step is to put the card into a computer and see if you can access the files there. Of course, it's nicest to do this as soon as possible, but if you don't have a computer easily accessible while traveling, put the card in a safe place and check it when you get home. That will make it clear if it's a card problem or a camera problem. Even if the pictures can be copied off okay (whew!), I wouldn't trust the card again.

Also in the future: don't leave all of your eggs in the collection basket. When I'm traveling, I make sure to copy everything to my laptop at the end of the day, and if possible where I am, then upload those photos to cloud backup nightly. If that's not possible, you may want to look at some of the solutions suggested [in this question about travel backups](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-can-i-backup-my-raw-photos-while-travelling-without-internet-access).

Comment: If I might add something to this answer that I already +1'd: **Related:** ["Recover data from SD card"](https://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card)

Comment: As it turns out after connecting it to PC I managed to retrieve them and upload them all to dropbox. When sync is done (my internet is horrible, I live in Cyprus and I only have like 1mb/s upload speed) I will try again with the card and see what happens