# Best way to backup/edit RAW photos while travelling abroad with bad Internet access?

Tags: raw, travel, backup

This question is a duplicate. In particular a duplicate of these questions:

- [How can I backup my RAW photos while travelling without Internet access?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-can-i-backup-my-raw-photos-while-travelling-without-internet-access)
- [How can I backup my photos while travelling?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/533/how-can-i-backup-my-photos-while-travelling)

Both very good resources, but technology is always advancing, the 4 year old questions are not. The Stackexchange format doesn't take into account updates to older questions, hence I'm asking anew.

The options for **backing up** presented so far:

- Options where the backup includes *sending home* stuff or just being *really careful*

  - Multiple memory cards
  - Portable DVD/CD burner with integrated card reader
  - Portable hard drive (HDD/SSD) with integrated card reader
  - Netbook (*this was 4 years ago, what to do today?*)
  - Tablet
- Options where the backup includes some *online* functionality

  - DropBox / OneDrive / Box some cloud storage
  - Custom NAS at home

The options for **editing** are pretty limited:

- Netbook (again, what to do today?)
- Laptop
- Tablet
- Some funky custom RasberryPi solution

**Have I missed anything important? Is there anything new I forgot? Portable Blueray drive? Magic Internet able to upload Gigabytes of RAW images from the middle of nowhere?**

When thinking of far-away travels in non-first-world countries I don't think the cloud solution is viable. Being stuck in some pretty awful (speed wise) Internet Cafes I know it is a hassle to upload just one image of 5MB. Now imagining backing one of my 16GB CF cards... Impossible. I think the only solution is to send stuff home. I like the idea of DVDs, but that would always take a lot of DVDs when using large CF cards.

Editing wise for e.g. Blogging there is no real way around taking a small laptop/netbook which of course sucks if you're doing longer travels.

Comment: Could you please clarify why none of the answers to your own question is a viable one? Why does `taking a small laptop/netbook [...] of course suck`? This does not hold true in general.

Comment: See [How Do I “Refresh” a Question?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-do-i-refresh-a-question)

Comment: Pretty sure this fits into the category of an inappropriate question for this site due to it becoming obsolete over time. It as much declares this up front since it says it is a duplicate of other questions that suffer the same problem.

Comment: how about a battery powered HDD with an SD card slot? http://www.amazon.co.uk/Passport-Wireless-Wi-Fi-Mobile-Storage/dp/B00N4QG8MQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1434575000&sr=8-1&keywords=mypassport+wireless

Comment: Thanks for your comments, especially @mattdm - so there is a ways to refresh a question.
The answers in the original questions are still valid, but most of the products are not available anymore. So it is always interesting to see "what else" is out there. Question is closed and that is ok.

Answer (score 1):

- Get multiple cards, so that you don't have to delete them.
- If you want a backup, in addition to multiple cards get a device like Nexto or HyperDrive with SSD drive inside. SSDs are worth the price here, they take less power and are shock resistant. They are lighter, too. Btw. it may be quite a bit cheaper if you get diskless device and buy the SSD on your own. Some of the devices have replaceable Li-Ion batteries, which gives longer life in conditions without access to power. These devices can be easily used in the field.
- Alternative to the backup device would be a laptop like the new 12 inch MacBook. The backup devices are not cheap either and the laptop has additional utility as an editor and allows Internet connection where available.

Answer (score -1):

A new option are wireless card reader / router / USB host combinations. They are usually about the size of a smartphone with own battery inside.

The combination of such a device with a big USB stick is cheap and light enough to carry around all day. I use a Kingston MLW221 and a 64GB SanDisk Cruzer Fit stick which hides in the USB port. Less than 50€ and 100g combined.

To do a backup, insert the SD card into the device, connect to it over WIFI using your smartphone and copy the pictures from the SD card to the USB stick.