# Photo backups via USB Hub + card reader + tablet + external HDD

Tags: travel, sdcard, backup, android, usb

Yes, it's another question about photo backups during traveling. But it's not a duplicate of [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/924/how-can-i-backup-my-raw-photos-while-travelling-without-internet-access) and [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/533/how-can-i-backup-my-photos-while-travelling) because I'm asking about specific way of backuping and will it work or no.

I have D750 and Nexus 9 tablet. I'm thinking about buying usb hub + card reader device like [this device](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-ports-USB-2-0-HUB-with-Multi-card-Reader-Combo-for-SD-MMC-M2-MS-MP-All-In-One-/231276125467) , so i can connect it via OTG to tablet. If i'm connecting external HDD via OTG to tablet, then it works fine and i can copy.

But can i connect table to USB hub + card reader, then connect external HDD to USB hub, and also insert SD cart to card reader. Will tablet understand that there are connected two devices - SD card and external HDD, so i can directly copy from SD card to HDD without copying photos to tablet.

As D750 has 24Mpx, then copying photos to tablet, and then from tablet to HDD takes a lot of time, so i'm thinking how it can be improved.

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider a device like the [Western Digital MyPassport Wireless](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=1330) which skips the middleman and uses your tablet as a control panel.  (It can also be plugged directly into a USB port and used as an external hard drive.)

Comment: WD MyPassport Wireless also has a built-in card reader. Good review here: http://www.lynda.com/articles/my-passport-wireless-review

Comment: Thanks for comments! WD MyPassport looks interesting. I'll check it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an USB hub on your tablet, I have a similar setup with my (rooted) Nexus 7 to read different USB key and it works.

However, you may have power issues if you are using a hard drive. The power output of your tablet is probably about 500mA. Check the consumption of your HDD. If it's higher or close to 500mA, you will have to use some external power source.